# Azure Function App (Backend) 401 Error when accessing from Azure App Service Frontend

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

we have a problem and i dont see anything which i can do for now. I've already followed for example this article but i does not work for now: [Azure Function App as Backend](https://medium.com/@sumindaniro/azure-function-app-as-the-backend-api-for-webapps-reactjs-c6a6ce26246)

Azure AD Authentication is configured in our Azure Function App and with postman i can connect with a bearer token to the function app.
[Function App Authentication is configured with error 401 for apis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy2QR.png)

I can see in the browser that there is always this error when we open the frontend app. There is no access to the Azure AD secured backend function app from the frontend: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)**

i exposed the api from the app registration of the backend function app and gave them invoke delegated rights to the frontend app registration like in the blog article. CORS is configured too.
[App Reg Invoke Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgkS8.png)

is there anything i can do? We login to our Frontend App Service with Azure AD credentials and this token should give access to the backend service function app too so there is nothing unprotected in the public internet. But frontend get always this 401 error.

Comment: is it configured with the same AAD app registration on both front end and backend ?

Comment: No Frontend and Backend have there own seperate AAD App Registrations and i've exposed the API with Invoke Scope from Backend App Reg to Frontend App Reg.

Comment: you would need to provide some more details / code on how you configure your applications

Comment: You mean more screenshots of the config in azure? (App Regs, App Service, Function App, ...) ?

Comment: Could you share the jwt token sent to the backend api ? and how is the backend auth is configured ? Rather not screenshot as it make thing difficult for people to help troubelshhooting

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario from my end :***

***When you decode the bearer token ,***
[image]

- Check issuer url and audience received

[image]

- Also if issuer url has **v2** endpoint ,Make sure the accessTokenAcceptedVersion is set to 2  other wise null or 1

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "id": "4axxxxxxx039",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    ...

}
```

- Try including function app url ***`https://kafnapprepo.azurewebsites.net`***
  in allowed audiences. Along with the **clientId** of the app and AppId uri

[image]

- and make sure the permissions are granted admin consent.

[image]